# Trying to redirect messages from one channel to another one

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am getting this error on the code below:

> (node:13760) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read
> property 'send' of undefined

```js
bot.on('message', async (message) => {
  message
    .delete({ timeout: 10 })
    .catch((err) =>
      logger.error(`Could not delete message (Error: ${err.message})`),
    );

  // Checking if command was executed in report channel
  if (message.channel.name != 'from-user') {
    // Do nothing
    logger.info(
      `message has not been sent in the forwarding channel! Aborting request.`,
    );
  } else {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    await client.channels.cache.get('910109122572218378').send(message.content);
    console.log(message.content); // log messages
    return;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If the channel ID is correct, the channel is probably not cached. If you know the channel ID, you could [`fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch) the channel by this ID. If it's cached, it returns the cached channel:

```js
const channel = await client.channels.fetch(CHANNEL_ID)

await channel.send(message.content)
console.log(message.content) // log messages
```

`fetch()` returns a Promise, so you'll need to use `await`.